# Cannot append child with for loop

Tags: javascript, html

Why i cannot append numerous blocks with this `for` loop?

```
var di = document.createElement("div");
di.className = 'box';
di.style.width = '100px';
di.style.height = '100px';

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    document.body.appendChild(di);
}
```

This one works, however:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var di = 'di' + [i],
        di = document.createElement("div");
    di.className = 'box';
    di.style.width = '100px';
    di.style.height = '100px';
    document.body.appendChild(di);
}
```

But why the first one doesn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first sample, the same dom element is appended all the time, because it is defined outside the loop. In the second one, you correctly create a new element for each iterations.

If you want, you can create a copy of an exising element by using `cloneNode`. The first example could be re-written like:

```
var di = document.createElement("div");
di.className = 'box';
di.style.width = '100px';
di.style.height = '100px';

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    document.body.appendChild(di.cloneNode());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because one element can't be in several places at once. You have to create one new instance for each element that you want to add in the page.

Comment: @plalx: What are you talking about?