# I cannot append elements with jQuery during javascript loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

There is one [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677972/cannot-append-child-with-for-loop), but I still not understand why I can't do the following:

```
            var numLoaded = document.createElement('span')
            numLoaded = document.createElement('span')
            numLoaded.style= "color:red;font-weight:bold";

            numLoaded.innerHTML = " Number of loaded results: "+0;

            $("#resultsCounter").append(numLoaded)

            for (var i = ((json.length)-1); i >= 0; i--) { 
                newDiv = document.createElement("div");
                newDiv.id = +i+1;
                newDiv.innerHTML = newDiv.innerHTML+"..."

                numLoaded.innerHTML = " Number of loaded results: "+newDiv.id;
                $("#resultsCounter").empty(); // should remove my span
                $("#resultsCounter").append(numLoaded) // should add my span with new content
                $("#results").prepend(newDiv)
            }
```

After this all as output I see only last added element after whole cycle ends. During cycle iteration it appends to DOM no child, even if it is already created. I want to append always the same element `<span>` but in every iteration with updated number.

Why child element is added to DOM only after cycle ends? How to update it in cycle? Do I need to recreate that element after every loop iteration? It is way to speed up this process?

Comment: Why don't you just set new counter value like $(element).text(counter) instead of .innerHTML with append?

Comment: every iteration will overwrite your span at all. That's why you see just the last element. do you want to get a counter that will increase while loading like a progress bar?

Comment: @AlexSlipknot if i got it right OP wants to see like: "1", then "1" disappears and appears "2" and then "2" disappears and appears "3" and so on.

Comment: @LelioFaieta yes... something like number in progress bar ... but this is a bit special, because I count down due to later `prepend()`... but the sense is the same

Comment: @LelioFaieta Overwrites at all... yes, but I want to see that change how it overwrites... or it is so quick that JS is not quick enough to add that new element to DOM ?

Comment: js is quick enough to go through each step of the for loop that you will not see the intermediate changes. That's why @AlexSlipknot was suggesting you to append instead of replacing

Comment: Hmm, now I understand... and as far as `.createElement()` operation take more time, due to that I will see respond if I recreate element every iteration ... and now understand what @Robin wrote as an answer "effectively overwriting itself" - too quick enough to see changes ...

Comment: i don't understand why you are using half jquery and half javascript

Comment: @NegiRox - for study purposes, its just a test project, I know that it is not correct formal approach

Comment: @AlexSlipknot because your solution not works and do the same thing, I will see only last element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you only create the element once, before the list. Then in the loop you are changing the `innerHtml` of the element, and adding it - but because it is the same element (the same JS object being referenced each time), it's effectively overwriting itself.

You just need to move these lines which create the element:

```
var numLoaded = document.createElement('span')
numLoaded = document.createElement('span')
numLoaded.style= "color:red;font-weight:bold";

numLoaded.innerHTML = " Number of loaded results: "+0;
```

*inside* the loop.

Comment: Still not understand why after overwriting itself there is no new value in that overwritten element ... it should be there if it overwrites with new values... but if I want understand it ...before loop, the JS remember the state of object after first append ... and during loop I cannot changed it because it inserts last known object out of loop?